# How to debug an application on a different network location using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I have a Server on the Internet which run a web application, I would like to know if it is possible to use Visual Studio from my local machine to connect to that Server and debug some code, using break points and so on.
My local machine and Server are on a different network and Server is accessible only on the Internet.

Comment: I have tried, but many articles talking about Ethernet connection (for my understanding a local network), I am not sure..... as I need over the Internet remote connection

Comment: Actually I have never done it over Internet, I assumed it would work but nae: "Debugging over the internet is not supported." ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx))

Comment: I use Remote debugging only for mobile app (till wm 6.5) and in vs 2008. In web i tried but as GibboK i cound' t made it.